# How do I save ./configure command line build options?

Tags: makefile, configure

I'm building a program by running

```
./configure --example-option-1 --example-option-2 --etc
```

then

```
make && make install
```

Is there a way to save those `./configure` options so that next time I run `./configure` they are applied by default?

That is, later on I might want to run

```
./configure --example-option-3
```

And have previously-saved options also apply. Or better yet, add `--example-option-3` to the same "options file" then just run `./configure` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by means of [`xargs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) which takes the arguments for the command to be executed from the standard input.

For saving the configuration into the file `config`:

```
echo --example-option-1 --example-option-2 --etc | tee config | xargs ./configure
```

That is, the file `config` will contain the arguments that were given at `echo`'s command line:

```
$ cat config
--example-option-1 --example-option-2 --etc
```

For retrieving the saved configuration from this file `config`:

```
cat config | xargs ./configure
```

That is, `./configure` will be executed with the arguments obtained at the standard input by means of `xargs`.

If later, you want to apply that saved configuration and an additional option, `--example-option-3`, then:

```
cat config | xargs ./configure --example-option-3
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't say exactly why you are re-running `configure`, but just to point out that `configure` creates a `config.status` script.  That script will recreate all the templated files using the configuration options you provided originally.

You can also use the `config.status --recheck` command to re-run `configure` using the same set of command-line options as was originally provided.

And of course, if you use automake the generated makefiles will contain rules to automatically update all these files whenever any template, or `configure.ac`, is modified so you don't have to do it by hand; just run `make`.

So if you have a configured directory already you don't need anything special to redo the configuration using the same arguments.